# How to have root domain accept alpanumeric parameter without route conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have my root controller accept a short alphanumeric parameter that is generated by the app:

```
mysite.com/5g3fj6
```

How would I best go about implementing this in a way that the parameter does not conflict with other routes such as mysite.com/signup

At the same time I would like to avoid having to add an intermediary "/i/" which would make typing in the domain and parameter harder for users:

```
mysite.com/i/5g3fj6
```

Comment: Have you tried using a parameterised named route?

Comment: @Jon Could you elaborate please? The last link would be assigned to match '/i/:id', to: 'root#id_controller' But I would like to avoid that as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using routes constraints.  Example: if you are using devise for login/registration stuffs make sure that devise related declarations are on the top of the routes.rb file:

```
# config/routes.rb

devise_scope :user do
  get 'signup', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
end 

# this will redirect any request matching the expected URL format.
get '/:the_id', constraints: { the_id: /[a-z0-9]{6}/ }, to: 'posts#show'
```

The route above will link requests like 'mysite.com/5g3fj6' to action :show in PostsController.  The log will show something like below:

```
Started GET "/5g3fj6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-30 00:27:10 +0800
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"the_id"=>"5g3fj6"}
```

You can now use 'the_id' inside the 'show' method to do something like "Post.find_by_slug( params[:the_id] )".

Hope that helps. :)

Cheers!